# Find first occure in pandas df for a given column

Tags: python, pandas

For each customer_id and partition_date, I would like to find the first date a given customer_id appears in the dataset. This is what I've tried so far, but I've been getting the error below:

```
df['first_seen_date'] = df.sort_values('partition_date').groupby('customer_id').first()

error:  Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

df

```
customer_id  partition_date  
24242        01.01.2020
24242        02.01.2020
24242        04.01.2020
35439        06.01.2020
35439        05.01.2020
35439        07.01.2020
```

desired output df

```
customer_id  first_seen_date
24242        01.01.2020
35439        05.01.2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, assign to new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('partition_date').groupby('customer_id', as_index=False).first()
```

Or use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('partition_date').drop_duplicates('customer_id')
```